# About Splines in GeometryNodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created an animation that places objects on a spline and moves them. I want to rotate the object along the direction of travel, so I used a curve tangent, but the objects at the start and end points are wrong.
Please let me know if anyone knows how to solve this problem.[image]

Comment: Hello. A solution might be to use a spline that is slightly longer by one control point at start and end, and start instantiating on the second control point, that way you have the tangent information

Comment: Hello! Gorgious san!
Thank you for your instruction.
I will try to do it the way you gave me!
I think you are using attribute, am I correct?
I'm not so sure because I haven't used it much.
I didn't word it well enough, but I also want to keep the object looping using wrap.